# Sum over variable in array using reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to sum over the number of calls in my array 'data'. I've found the 'reduce' function, but don't know how to select the calls part of the array. Here's my attempt at doing it:

```
data = {
        links: [
                  {source: 0,target: 1, calls: 20, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 2, calls: 5, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 3, calls: 8, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 4, calls: 3, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 5, calls: 2, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 6, calls: 3, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 7, calls: 5, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 8, calls: 2, texts:0}
                ]
        }

var total_calls = data.links.calls.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making this a little bit more reusable?

```js
data = {
        links: [
                  {source: 0,target: 1, calls: 20, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 2, calls: 5, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 3, calls: 8, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 4, calls: 3, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 5, calls: 2, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 6, calls: 3, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 7, calls: 5, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 8, calls: 2, texts:0}
                ]
        }

pluck = function(ary, prop) {
  return ary.map(function(x) { return x[prop] });
}

sum = function(ary) {
  return ary.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b }, 0);
}

result = sum(pluck(data.links, 'calls'))
document.write(result)
```

Comment: Both solutions are quite nice, but for my purposes it's actually perfect that's reusable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the `data.links` array, like this

```
var total_calls = data.links.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
  return result + currentObject.calls;
}, 0);
console.log(total_calls);
// 48
```